# In R, how to pass PostgreSQL column contents to dbGetQuery using param

Tags: r, postgresql, rshiny

I am trying to query my PostgreSQL DB in R, using dbGetQuery(). Below are what I have done so far:

**This command ran through without issue** I have it here just to show how the database was queried

```
test_db = dbPool(drv = dbDriver("PostgreSQL", max.con = 100),
           dbname = "TEST",
           host = "localhost",
           user = "postgres",
           password = "password",
           idleTimeout = 3600000
        )
```

**This command ran with error**

```
dbGetQuery(test_db, 
       "select * from public.table1 where tag = ?", 
       params = 'tag_col_content1') 

Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: ...lect * from public.table1 where tag = ?
                                                  ^
)
NULL
Warning message:
In postgresqlQuickSQL(conn, statement, ...) :
  Could not create execute: select * from public.table1 where tag = ?
```

I have to suspect it has something to do with the double/single quotes, but could not figure out what exactly. I also tried **the following which works**:

```
dbGetQuery(test_db, 
       "select * from public.table1 where tag = 'tag_col_content1'")
```

Please note that it is important for me to pass value to the SQL statement because eventually this line will be used interactively in Rshiny. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, the official way to spell place holders is `$1`, `$2`, ... `$9`,... not `?`.  Some drivers will automatically parse and transform queries for you, but evidently not this one.

When I used `$1` in place of `?`, it works.

Comment: Thank you @jjanes! It is working now! I am very new to Postgresql, and ? is used in dbGetQuery's official menu lol...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want to supply user input to the where clause of your query. You could probably do some mental gymnastics with tidy eval, but `paste0()` seems like an easy fix:

```
param <- "'tag_col_content1'"

dbGetQuery(test_db, 
           paste0("select * from public.table1 where tag = ", param))
```

Comment: Thank you @ConnorKrenzer. I am not very sure if this approach will fix my concern fully, but I see a new error: Could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  column "tag_col_contents1" does not exist. Any idea why postgresql recognize this as a column name? (Tag is the column name)

Comment: @Helene it sounds like you didn't include the literal single quotes inside the string assigned to param.  But anyway, this method is fragile and prone to injection attacks.